# Running Postgres from within a Docker Container

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to build a docker image that will have Postgres running internally. This image is run as a Jenkins Agent and uses Postgres to execute GraphQL tests.

I've been able to install Postgres on the image, but don't have enough familiarity on getting it to start up when the image start.

Is a start-up script the best way to go?

Comment: My default approach would be to `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres` to run the [Docker Hub `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).  Is this enough for you?  If not, what have you done already, and what specific problem are you running into?

Comment: This detaches it though, right? I tried this and then it makes the docker image inaccessible to the jenkins pipeline. Let me try it again, though

Comment: To answer your last question, when my tests execute, they are all failing because data isn't being written to the localhost database

Comment: The Jenkins pipeline documentation has [a specific example of running a test with a `mysql` container](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers) that could also be informative to you.

Comment: That is informative, didn't even think about running commands from within the pipeline. Going to try that out